# Calculate 3D gradients with openCv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV and C++ to make a 3D HOG function (I already made the 2D one). I have a 3 dimensional Mat (x,y,z) where the z value is the depth info of the pixel (x,y) (a combination of the 2D color Image and the depthImage from the Kinect). The next step is to calculate gradients of x, y and z, in the 2D HOG function I used Sobel to do that :

```
Mat gx, gy;
Sobel(img, gx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 1);
Sobel(img, gy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 1);
```

But when it comes to the 3D gradients,  I did not find a way to do it. Is there any simple way for that???

Comment: "Is there any simple way for that???" I don't believe so; there's not an OpenCV function for it AFAIK. With that said it's not particularly difficult to code your own Sobel filter, but you'll need to compute it manually for each 3D voxel.

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually I am trying a new method where I make 3 mat XY,XZ,YZ and then get 3 HOG descriptors ans concatenate them, I don't know if it will work well but I'm trying.